# Reading specific sections of new lines

Tags: python, arrays, file-io

I'm trying to save multiple lines from a file into an array.  I only want a few sections of the line though, here is few lines for example:

```
SAM_2216_geotag.JPG -81.5285781 41.0382292  418.13  279.04  -0.01   6.96
SAM_2217_geotag.JPG -81.5290933 41.0382309  418.94  279.34  -1.08   6.03
SAM_2218_geotag.JPG -81.5296101 41.0382294  419.31  287.49  -0.01   4.79
```

I would like to save all the first sets of numbers in their own array and the set of second numbers.

```
Array1= [-81.5285781, -81.5290933, -81.5296101]
Array2= [41.03822292, 41.0382309, 41.0382294]
```

So far, I am able to save every new line into an array but I'm having trouble getting rid of the unwanted data.  Here is one element of my current array:

```
SAM_2216_geotag.JPG\t-81.5285781\t41.0382292\t418.13\t279.04\t-0.01\t6.96\n'
```

If anyone could help me get the array how I would like it that would be a big help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to split your data so you can work with the individual bits. Try something like

```
columns = line.split()
```

[documentation on string.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Then you can put them into arrays as you like. For example (using a loop):

```
array1 = []
array2 = []
for line in lines:
    columns = line.split()
    array1.append(columns[1])
    array2.append(columns[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using re.search ( https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search ), split ( https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split ), Zip (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip ) and map (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map )

```
import re
out=[]

#Sample lines, you can just get these from file
line1 = "SAM_2216_geotag.JPG -81.5285781 41.0382292  418.13  279.04  -0.01   6.96"
line2 ="SAM_2217_geotag.JPG -81.5290933 41.0382309  418.94  279.34  -1.08   6.03"
line3 = "SAM_2218_geotag.JPG -81.5296101 41.0382294  419.31  287.49  -0.01   4.79"


#Create an array that has only the values you need. 
#You can replace the for below by using 'with open(file) as fH: and for line in fH'
for line in (line1, line2, line3):
    #line1 output: ['-81.5285781', '41.0382292', '418.13', '279.04', '-0.01', '6.96']
    out.append([x.strip() for x in line.split() if re.search('^[\d.-]+$', x.strip())])
#zip all the lists of out into list of tuples and then convert them to list of lists
#Please note that if your array lengths are uneven, you will get the shortest length output
print map (list, zip(*out))
```

**output:**

```
[['-81.5285781', '-81.5290933', '-81.5296101'], 
 ['41.0382292', '41.0382309', '41.0382294'], 
 ['418.13', '418.94', '419.31'], 
 ['279.04', '279.34', '287.49'], 
 ['-0.01', '-1.08', '-0.01'], 
 ['6.96', '6.03', '4.79']
]
```